# java - replace a specific length of a digit in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I want to *convert to asterisk the first 12 digits* of a 16 digit number in a sentence.

The last *4 digits should be visible*.

**Example input:**

```
String test = "test/1234567890121123/121/test";
String test2 = "hey: 1234567890123456";
```

**Expected output:**

```
String test = "test/************1123/121/test";
String test2 = "hey: ************3456";
```

**Note:** the input is dynamic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this option:

```
String test = "test/1234567890121123/121/test";
String test2 = "hey: 1234567890123456";
test = test.replaceAll("\\b\\d{12}(?=\\d{4}\\b)", "************"); // 12 *'s
System.out.println(test);
```

The trick here is to surgically replace 12 digits at the beginning of a 16 digit number.  To do this, we can search for `\b\d{12}(?=\d{4}\b)`.  The final portion of that pattern is a positive *lookahead*, which asserts, but does not consume.  Since the lookahead does not actually consume, what it matches will not be affected by the replacement.

### Demo

Comment: Works fine, thank you sir !
Thanks for the comment as well.

Comment: No lookahead needed. Just capture the second group.

Comment: @JackFlamp Well I'm no Wiktor Stribicew, but I know my way around a regex engine :-)

Comment: @userunknown Not sure about performance, but I might guess that avoiding an unnecessary capture would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Java:

```
test.replaceAll ("([0-9]{12})([0-9]{4})", "************$2/")
```

If only expressions of the exact right length (16) shall match, not longer ones:

```
-> "0123456789012345".replaceAll ("\\b([0-9]{12})([0-9]{4})\\b", "************$2/");
|  Expression value is: "************2345/"
|    assigned to temporary variable $18 of type String
```

Fails, too long:

```
-> "01234567890123456".replaceAll ("\\b([0-9]{12})([0-9]{4})\\b", "************$2/");
|  Expression value is: "01234567890123456"
|    assigned to temporary variable $19 of type String
```